# jenkins: Override text in Build with Parameters

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized pipeline `my-job` in a multibranch pipeline. In the "Build with Parameters" page, I see:

```
Pipeline my-job

This build requires parameters:

<list of input fields>
```

I would like to override the text `This build requires parameters:` from `Jenkinsfile`. Is that possible? How?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I have text describing the job, its inputs and outputs, in its "main" page with `setDescription` on the job. This is not the place I happen to be looking when configuring the job, so I'd like to have the same description there as well.

Comment: I suspect that this wont be easy/possible to achieve. It would probably require some amount of fiddling with Jenkins intern objects. An easier hack would be to set your text as the description of a dummy parameter. Otherwise this might be a good starting point to look into https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/hudson/model/Messages.properties